# change IE settings Programmatically

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to make a windows application that adds a URL too the "Trusted sites" of IE. this part works.
solution - http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/05/15/c-code-for-changing-internet-explorer-security-settings-and-net-security-policy-to-run-windows-forms-based-activex-with-full-trust/

But i need to change same settings also. i need this :
"Access data sources across domains" needs to be "Enable" 
"Download unsigned ActiveX controls" needs to be "Prompt" 
"Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe" needs to be "Enable"

this is what i have, but it won't work

```
    private void UpdateDataSource() 
    {
        RegistryKey ChangeSettings = Registry.Users;
        ChangeSettings = ChangeSettings.OpenSubKey(".DEFAULT\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\2", true);

        // "Access data sources across domains" - "Enable" 
        ChangeSettings.SetValue("1406", "0", RegistryValueKind.DWord);

        // "Download unsigned ActiveX controls" - "Prompt" 
        ChangeSettings.SetValue("1004", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);

        // "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting" - "Enable" 
        ChangeSettings.SetValue("1201", "0", RegistryValueKind.DWord);

        ChangeSettings.Close();
    }
```

source http://www.hohmanns.de/

Comment: This reads like: *"how do I lower every security setting in IE for a user's account?"*. Not to mention you won't be able to do this if the security is set via group policy.

Comment: Slugster - do you have a link to "how do I lower every security setting in IE for a user's account?" maybe it can help me

Comment: Lol. After you post that link @slugster, perhaps you could find the *"how do I bypass every security feature in an Operating System?"* It must exist, right @Simon?

Comment: @Simon: did any of the answers provide a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it works:

```
private void UpdateDataSource()      
{         
    RegistryKey ChangeSettings = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\3", true);          
    // "Access data sources across domains" - "Enable"          
    ChangeSettings.SetValue("1406", "0", RegistryValueKind.DWord);          
    // "Download unsigned ActiveX controls" - "Prompt"          
    ChangeSettings.SetValue("1004", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);          
    // "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting" - "Enable"          
    ChangeSettings.SetValue("1201", "0", RegistryValueKind.DWord);          
    ChangeSettings.Close();    
}
```

Comment: This did work for me.. Thanks.. Created a console program and ran the code. The setting reflected immediately,

Comment: @Rohit, thanks for your answer. I have same problem for changing Microsoft office setting (change number setting to context mode). Do you have any idea?

Comment: i tried this , it could be worked in localhost perfectly. but in webserver IIS it has not worked

Answer (score 1):

You can visit this web site : http://networkdog.blogspot.com/2011/04/internet-explorer-9-configurations.html About internet explorer 9 registry key. You can find all configration key.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change it manually in IE, then check what is changed in the registry and find a way to change it (by changing the registry directly), or find a better way to change that particular tag.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Have tried too see the change in the registry. But i can't see a it

Comment: @slugster: ok thanks ... I guess this accounts for all (partial) answers or directions to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Fantastic, it works.. This is the key:

RegistryKey ChangeSettings = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3", true);